# Delegate factory in Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, ioc-container, autofac

Autofac got [delegate factories](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories), but I can't find any information about how to implement this in [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/). The reason for me wanting to use this is to avoid referencing the container itself, but to be able to dynamically create new objects of the specified type.

Is there something similar I can do to achieve the same result?

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't this require a reference to the kernel itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the factory extension ([link](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki)).

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be what I was looking for.